# Memory Managing structure in tabeview

Tags: ios, iphone

I have facing memory issue, currently i am working on one magazine app, in that app i want to show article list. I am fetching server data and show the content in table view. I have programatically create a custom cell in that cell i am creating 3 labels and one imageview. But when i run the this app in simulator they are showing 60 Mb memory. i am confused how to resolve the memory.

Here is the sample i am implemented,

```
if (cell == nil)
{

    float cellHeight =[self managingHeight:indexPath.row withSection:indexPath.section];
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    UILabel *LBL_MainTitle = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(LEFT_SPACE, TOP_SPACE + CATEGORY_MAX_HEIGHT + (STND_SPACE*2), maximumLabelSize.width - STND_SPACE, 20)];
    [LBL_MainTitle setBackgroundColor:STAT_titleBackgroundClolor];
    [LBL_MainTitle setTextColor:STAT_titleTextColor];
    [LBL_MainTitle setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:STAT_titleFontName size:STAT_titleFontSize]];
    LBL_MainTitle.numberOfLines=0;
    LBL_MainTitle.lineBreakMode=NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    [LBL_MainTitle setTag:2];
    LBL_MainTitle.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth & UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:LBL_MainTitle];
}
```

In this project i enabled ARC.

Please check this and let me know. Thanks

Comment: Are you only creating a single cell? Or are you allocating a new cell each time? (in you cellForRowAtIndexPath method)

Answer (score 0):

You should reuse the cell by below method.

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier;
```

Write code in below way:

```
static NSString *identifier = @"identifier";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];
if (cell == nil)
{
    float cellHeight =[self managingHeight:indexPath.row withSection:indexPath.section];
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:identifier];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    UILabel *LBL_MainTitle = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(LEFT_SPACE, TOP_SPACE + CATEGORY_MAX_HEIGHT + (STND_SPACE*2), maximumLabelSize.width - STND_SPACE, 20)];
    [LBL_MainTitle setBackgroundColor:STAT_titleBackgroundClolor];
    [LBL_MainTitle setTextColor:STAT_titleTextColor];
    [LBL_MainTitle setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:STAT_titleFontName size:STAT_titleFontSize]];
    LBL_MainTitle.numberOfLines=0;
    LBL_MainTitle.lineBreakMode=NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    [LBL_MainTitle setTag:2];
    LBL_MainTitle.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth & UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:LBL_MainTitle];
}
```

Comment: yes i have used that one also
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

Answer (score 0):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyReuseIdentifier";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault  reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    }

    float cellHeight =[self managingHeight:indexPath.row withSection:indexPath.section];        
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    UILabel *LBL_MainTitle = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(LEFT_SPACE, TOP_SPACE + CATEGORY_MAX_HEIGHT + (STND_SPACE*2), maximumLabelSize.width - STND_SPACE, 20)];
    [LBL_MainTitle setBackgroundColor:STAT_titleBackgroundClolor];
    [LBL_MainTitle setTextColor:STAT_titleTextColor];
    [LBL_MainTitle setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:STAT_titleFontName size:STAT_titleFontSize]];
    LBL_MainTitle.numberOfLines=0;
    LBL_MainTitle.lineBreakMode=NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    [LBL_MainTitle setTag:2];
    LBL_MainTitle.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth & UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:LBL_MainTitle];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: same like that i am added Description Label and imageview also, At least in 50 cell they have.And Still the app are showing more than 50 MB?

Comment: 2 things:
1. Are you sure this is because of the tableview and not because of some other activity in the app? Instruments will show you that.
2. What are the image sizes?

Comment: For image showing,i am using the SDWebImage Library, i have checked Library Cache also, they are showing me images folder size is 2 Mb. First i fetch the data from server and then store into database, after that i am showing that data into tableview. It and it showing me still more than 50 Mb.